# What are these fishing things called "Pre-rigged sets"?

Tags: fishing

(Note: I'm a total noob in fishing).

I've seen some so-called "*pre-rigged sets*" with a hook and a float attached onto some line and wound around a piece of plastic:

[image: pre-rigged fishing set]

They usually come with some **~7m** (20ft) line. Which brings me to my question:

**What am I supposed to do with that line?**

- It is not long enough for use by itself.
- Joining it with the rest of my line would make a nasty knot, which would interfere with casting.
- Cut it and splice just above the bobber?
- ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's for cane poles and the like.

https://www.basspro.com/shop/en/bass-pro-shops-cane-pole?hvarAID=shopping_googleproductextensions

You literally tie the line to a stick and drop it in the water. Really great for kids, quick fishing, fishing off of bridges, river fishing from overhangs, etc. Honestly, it's a lot of fun, the largest drawback is that you can't fish from the shore but have to be over the water. But that's easy enough to do in costal areas.

Comment: Oh, so [this rig](https://www.intertoys.nl/p/werphengel-op-kaart/1136833) my son got for birthday is complete baloney? It came with no instructions whatsoever and we couldn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: I'd say so, but i cant read rhe site

Comment: @rustyx, the picture in the link is of the cheap version of a proper rig, usable as starter or follow up of the cane pole, the one in the picture is much smaller, only the line on a holder ready for the simple cane pole.

Comment: @Willeke exactly, it's like a combination of two unrelated things...

Answer (score 0):

I have spend plenty an afternoon, sitting along the local shipping canal or one of the fishing ponds in the area, when I was a child.
If I was lucky there was a three part cane fishing pole and if I was unlucky I got the use of a bamboo one piece 'pole' which was a bean stick if not in use for fishing.

Tie the end of the string to the top of the pole, the purpose made one had a loop for that, the bean stick ones required a bit more tying skill.
The roll the line from the holder till you can hold the pole and holder comfortably and walk to the water, roll the rest of the line from the holder and attach bait to the hook, move the top of the stick out over the water and  lower it till the float floats and wait till it dips or till you run out of patience, pull out, attach new bait and repeat. At the end of the day you would roll the line on the holder again and bring it home that way, to be used an other day.

In all the years of fishing I managed to get one carp, and that scared me out of wanting to try again.

Others in our area had a little more luck with the ready made lines but most people who were serious about angling would not use the ready made ones, those were for the kiddies and sometimes the partners (mostly wives) who did not really want to fish but wanted something to show why they were there.

[This kind of line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLNhv.jpg) and set-up is not for serious fishing, it is really a kiddies starting set and needs a pole to use it. (Although some people did use it with just a bit of wood to hold it in hand and pretend not to be fishing when the licenses were checked.

In a comment to an other answer there is a link to an other kind of [fishing starter set](https://www.intertoys.nl/p/werphengel-op-kaart/1136833), which is a simple but not basic pole with a winder, string and tackle. While still mostly a play thing, it is way over the one in the question. I would not expect this one to be used in serious fishing, adviced ages are 6 to 12 years, pole lenth 1.55 meter, but they do look like the poles serious anglers use.